# how to create an AVD manager in android studio

Tags: android

please i can someone tell me the best AVD to use with android studio which can emulate the device camera using the system web cam. i have tried using emulator and webcam and both each time the emulator refuses to start.

Comment: try with real device

Comment: try genymotion emulator it works with camera and webcam

Comment: I used genymotion and it works fine